# "Missing number, treated as zero" when returning length from function

Tags: lengths

This MWE fails when I return a length and some string (I noticed it when I tried to debug some Ti*k*Z macros I wrote).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{20mm}
\newcommand\getlength[1]{
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{1}{\mylength}{}
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{2}{\mylength + 10mm}{}
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{3}{\mylength}{}
}
\begin{document}
\getlength{1}
\getlength{2} % As soon as this line exists, ...
\getlength{3} % ...this line returns: "Missing number, treated as zero."
\end{document}
```

Why is that so and how can I make it work?

Comment: I will accept an answer that also explains, where the problem comes from.

Comment: \mylength expects a following number to assign the register. it doesn't output the current value. The first two commands do basically `\mylength=\mylength` and then print the + 10mm. And the last \mylength is missing its number.

Comment: So `\mylength5cm` would be equivalent to `\setlength{\mylength}{5cm}`? If you want the credit, I would take your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\mylength` expects a following number to assign the register. It doesn't output the current value.

So the first two commands do basically \mylength=\mylength and then print the `+ 10mm`. And the last `\mylength` is missing its number.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can prevent the error by returning `\the\mylength` instead, but I don't know yet why the problem arises.